# Scale changes when applying curve modifier

Tags: transforms

very annoying as sometimes it happen and sometime it doesn't (first curve is fine) i just want the cube to stay the same exact scale it has originally... i also apply both scale + rotation on both ... what can be done to fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you've scaled your curve and applied its scale, the radius of its vertices is no longer 1. So select your curve, go in *Edit* mode, select all the vertices, and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Set Curve Radius* (value 1 by default, that's what you want, but you can change it on the bottom of the T panel), or in the Tools panel of your 3D view (displayed with <kbd>T</kbd> on the left of the 3D view) go in *Tools* > *Curve Tools* > *Set Curve Radius* and choose a value of 1.

Comment: Just a slight correction: If the curve has varying radii (it doesn't, here, so it doesn't matter) then setting the _mean_ radius will do just that.. it won't set all the radii to 1. If you want to set all the radii to one value, you can do that in the Tool region, with _Curve Tools_ > _Set Curve Radius_.

Comment: oh yes you're right I'm going to edit

Comment: .. and showed me another way, too .. :)